# Filepicker.io - didPickMediaWithInfo: doesn't return specified information

Tags: filepicker.io

According to the iOS docs, FPPickerController:didPickMediaWithInfo: should return the following data:

Keys in the info dictionary
    FPPickerControllerFilename
    FPPickerControllerMediaType
    (When Possible) FPPickerControllerMediaURL
    (When Possible) FPPickerControllerRemoteURL
    (When Possible) FPPickerControllerOriginalImage

However, the only information I ever get is:

FPPickerControllerThumbnailImage = "<UIImage: 0x9712dd0>";

Is there anyway to get the Filename and/or RemoteURL before upload begins?

Comment: You should be getting the filename. Since filepicker hasn't done the file movements yet, you won't be getting a remote url until the operation is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is working as expected. The documentation was wrong and that has been fixed.

Comment: That being said, it seems a bit silly not to pass back things like filename and filesize and I could see that in future updates.